# Volume of length 32 has dim=(32,32,32)?

Tags: python, data-generation

I am trying to generate a data generator by my own following the example on the site here:https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

Now, I was stumbling about a piece of the following code:

```
  def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=32, dim=(32,32,32), n_channels=1,
                 n_classes=10, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()
```

Can someone tell me what `dim=(32,32,32)` means in this code?

They stated *"We put as arguments relevant information about the data, such as dimension sizes (e.g. a volume of length 32 will have dim=(32,32,32))"* but I still do not get what that means?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe in the Context of Keras data generator, dim=(32,32,32) simply means a constructor of 3D Numpy Array that will generate a random data that follows a 3 Dimensional Array which is more likely a converted Image

Comment: Ok, thanks! So, that means, if I would like to generate images with height and width of 224 and color space rgb, than dim has to be dim=(224,224,3)?

Comment: Since it is random, dim=(224,224,3) may produce more likely a 3 Images with width and Height of 224, color space rgb can be set in n_channels I believe